# iOS - Add multiple UIButton inside UIScrollView not scrolling smoothly

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton, smooth-scrolling

I'm adding (400+) `UIButton`s in `UIScrollview`, When I scrolls in `simulator` its working well, but in iPad its scrolling slowly.

[Here's](http://mocku.ps/ga24n5) what I'm doing.

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad {
> [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(180 * 24 , 22 * 40 + 200)];
> for (int e=0; e<12; e++) {
>     for(int i=0;i<24;i++)
>     {
>         UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
>         btn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
>         [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:248.0/255.0 green:248.0/255.0 blue:248.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
>
>
>         CALayer *layer = btn.layer;
>         layer.cornerRadius = 5.f;
>         layer.masksToBounds = YES;
>         layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
>         layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:190.0/255.0 green:190.0/255.0 blue:190.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor];
>
>         CGRect rect = btn.frame;
>         rect.size.height = 40;
>         rect.size.width = 50;
>         rect.origin.x =  100 * i;
>         rect.origin.y = 40 * e;
>         btn.frame = rect;
>
>         CAGradientLayer *shineLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
>         shineLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
>         shineLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
>                              (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:0.5f].CGColor,
>                              (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:0.7f].CGColor,
>                              (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:1.f].CGColor,
>                              (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:1.f].CGColor,
>                              (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:1.f].CGColor,nil];
>         [layer addSublayer:shineLayer];
>
>         UILabel *lblDes = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,40)];
>         lblDes.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
>         lblDes.numberOfLines = 3;
>         lblDes.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:4.0/255.0 green:106.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1];
>         lblDes.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
>         lblDes.text = @"adf";
>         lblDes.tag = -1;
>         lblDes.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11.f];
>
>         [btn addSubview:lblDes];
>         [scrollView addSubview:btn];
>     }
> }
> [super viewDidLoad];  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. }
> ```

Comment: iOS simulator is faster than the actual device , because it uses the computer resources.

Comment: Like Jossef explained, you cannot compare the speed from the simulator with the speed of your device. The simulator isnt slowed down to simulate the ipad! So its really important to test everything also on the device. Im really interested if its really necessary to add 400+ UIButtons on a screen, whats the case behind this?

Comment: Thanks i see it, but i don't know how do i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS simulator runs on Mac, which is a lot faster than actual Device.

It all depends on Your requirements (why You need so many buttons),

I would suggest adding an UIView as subview, and then in drawRect - draw necessary things. Then You could use gesture recogniser to find out location where user tapped. (as suggested from **tdubik**)

Other solution could be tableView. (which has possibility to reuse cells. You could add a button to each cell).

If tableView is not what you are looking for, and drawRect is too plain (as it will be without selection effects) - You could have one hidden UIButton, which (in highlighted state) then could be placed correspondingly where user tapped, and removed, when user removes touches from screen.

**EDIT**

When using drawrect - You can then add gesture recognizer for subview in which elements are drawn using drawrect:

```
CustomViewClass *mView = [CustomViewClass alloc] init];
```

...

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

singleTap.delegate = self;

singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[mView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

and then :

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{
    CGPoint mPoint = [tap locationInView:tap.view];

    int mOffset = 0; //beginning offset where buttons will start.

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) //how many rows of buttons? 20? 
    { 
        mOffset += 20; //your custom drawn button height + offset from previous button

        if(mPoint.y < mOffset) //now check - if y tapped position is lower than current button.y + its height, then we know what button we tapped.
        {
            //do something - we found button row!!
            break;
        }
    }

    mOffset = 0; //beginning x offset

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) //how many columns buttons? 20? 
    { 
        mOffset += 20; //your custom drawn button width + offset from previous button

        if(mPoint.x < mOffset) //now check - if x tapped position is lower than current button.x + its width, then we know what button we tapped.
        {
            //do something - we found button column!! at this point we know which button was tapped.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

*If You have 2 dimension button array, add the same checking for x coordinates.*

Comment: I use drawRect to draw a rectangle and want to create events on it as [button addTarget: self action: @ selector (btnPlay) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
How to do it

Comment: CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:190.0/255.0 green:190.0/255.0 blue:190.0/255.0 alpha:1].CGColor);
                CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(50,0,60 ,40);
                CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
                CGContextStrokePath(context);

Comment: Are You only interested in calling a function on the corresponding "button" tap?

Comment: Tap and draw rectangle like button.

Comment: Dear Treulands, can you support with this problem.. this is code for me -> http://www.mediafire.com/?t5xj3nz9yyr2d8d

Comment: Thanks for your help very enthusiastic, one more thing, how to be able to assign a tag to each rectangle, so I'll have to call the tag to edit or delete

Comment: Not possible. You need to understand, that what has been made in drawRect - is one big pile of art. When drawn, it basically is an image. You need to redraw again with necessary changes to change something. You could - store in array coordinates tho.. so You can easier know which element should be changed or somethin like that.

But as previously said - if You manage to do all your requirements in drawrect - it'll work veeerrrryy smoooth!!!

Answer (score 0):

Profile your application in instruments to be sure that buttons are reason of sluggishness.

Instead of UIButtons create UIView derived classes with gesture recogniser installed or just UIControl. The best approach will be to draw your views with drawRect method.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean,can you give me example to improve scroll speed on ipad

Comment: As suggested by *tdubik*. You should profile your application. However it clearly seen in your code that its not properly memory-managed. You should write `[lblDes release]; btn = nil;` after adding `btn` to `scrollview`.